# Let's get critical: Mar 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento - Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to evaluate 3rd party extensions?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-evaluate-3rd-party-extensions)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Remove "powered by Magento" from footer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/722/remove-powered-by-magento-from-footer)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Magento boilerplate / blank / skeleton / naked themes for theme development](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/959/magento-blank-skeleton-naked-themes-for-theme-development)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Cron crashes MySQL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/666/cron-crashes-mysql)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Best way to install Solr across Multiple Distributions?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/503/best-way-to-install-solr-across-multiple-distributions)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Simple catalog search block extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/599/simple-catalog-search-block-extension)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Magento cookie bug with WebKit based browsers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/796/magento-cookie-bug-with-webkit-based-browsers)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Adding a column to export but hiding from the grid?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369/adding-a-column-to-export-but-hiding-from-the-grid)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Magento Media Assets in Amazon S3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/462/magento-media-assets-in-amazon-s3)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [M2E Pro doesn't include Magento Tax rules in eBay item prices](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/780/m2e-pro-doesnt-include-magento-tax-rules-in-ebay-item-prices)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

Answer (score 7):

The site seems to have a great blend of questions at the moment and is clearly gaining traction from more technical users.

### Questions so far ...

If I were to break it down, the following categories of questions are apparent

- Server side performance

  - General guidance
  - **Server/hardware sizing**
  - **Configuration file requests/validation**
- Code-level fault resolution

  - CE/EE core bugs
  - 3rd party extension help/assistance
- Pro-active code development

  - Complex custom scripts (standalone/API)
  - Extension development/rewrites
- GUI guidance

  - Admin processes/settings
- **What extension is ...**

  - **... most suitable for**
  - **... best for**
  - **... better than**
- **Duplication/repeat questions (from the same users)**

The one's I've marked in **bold** are my only areas of concern. They're either unanswerable (without continual discussion), prone to bias/self-promotion, have potential to be out-of-date/irrelevant or just subject to opinion (not fact).

In terms of self-moderation, I think the community is working fairly well to scrub the wheat from the chaff; whilst they're not quite as super-quick as the ServerFault community, I think its certainly getting there.

### In conclusion

As a whole - the questions and answers are great - and the community is working hard to make this a great place for Magento help.

The answers on here comparatively speaking to others found on the web are **very good**. Magento has never had any core documentation/official guidance - so its always been a community effort via developer blogs to provide answers/information for the platform.

Magento.se has provided a unilateral knowledge-base of valuable Q&A resource that the community really needed *(lets be honest, no-one has the patience to wait for the MagentoCommerce forums to load!)*

### Special thanks to ...

I'd like to add my own special credits to Tim, Fabian Blechschmidt, Alex, benmarks, Alan Storm, Marius, Rick Kuipers, davidalger, Paul Grigoruta, philwinkle, jharrison.au, pzirkind, mpaepper, Tobias Zander, Kenny, Sander Mangel, Matthias Zeis, Ivan Chepurnyi, FlorinelChis and many others - for their moderation/edit efforts, good quality answers and questions.

Comment: Good analysis! I agree with your areas of concern. Once the site has pro-tem moderators appointed, they can help curtail the question repetition from the same users. We could (and should) do it too, but we don't spend as much time on Magento as the dedicated community moderators would, so that sort of thing is harder to notice.