# Moderators Needed

Tags: discussion, moderators

Every site needs people to handle moderation duties. While most of this can be done by folks using the site, there are a few tasks that [require special privileges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> Even with active community self-regulation, moderators occasionally need to intervene. Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

Initially, we (employees of Stack Exchange) act as moderators on a site. But a few weeks after a site enters public beta, we start looking for folks who would make good moderators and contacting them to see if they're willing to be [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) until the site has grown enough to allow for elections.

"Who should our moderators be" is one of [the 7 essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) we encourage every community to ask themselves, so usually this process is kicked off by the community around the end of the private beta. That doesn't seem to be the case this time, so I'm here to solicit nominations.

Here's what we're looking for in a moderator:

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Have sole control of the account (i.e. accounts used by multiple people aren't eligible).
> - Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

**If you're interested and qualified, volunteer here by posting an answer. If you know someone who would make a good moderator, nominate them.**

- Each nomination should be posted as an answer and it should include (at minimum) a link to the user's main and meta profile so we can check out their activity.
- *Self nominations are encouraged*.
- If you are nominated by someone else you should edit the answer and let us know if you accept or decline (explanation optional). If a nominee declines we will not delete the answer, as to not have someone else nominate them again.
- If you are nominating someone else, please mark the post as Community Wiki before saving. Meta doesn't allow suggested edits, so your nominee may be blocked from accepting the nomination.
- The nominations are not binding. If you are being considered by Stack Exchange, we will contact you by email and you will get an official confirmation at one point.

I'll give this post a few days, and then will approach some or all of the volunteers to see about forming the initial moderator team for this site.

Comment: Moderators are definitely needed. There are some span messages/questions that have to be addressed.

Comment: I'll ditto that. The content is now to the point where we are turning up in search results, new users not familiar with SE in general are coming on, not to mention new users joining just to post spam links. :)

Answer (score 22):

#### Ben Marks

I would like to nominate Ben Marks. Here is his [main profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/5/benmarks) and [meta profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/benmarks).

**EDIT: I accept and am pleased by this nomination.**

Answer (score 14):

#### sonassi (Ben Lessani)

I would happily put myself forward as a moderator.

I have ...

- Answered 117/1052 questions (11%)
- Visited the site consecutively for 107 days
- Reviewed questions and answers daily
- Cleaned up/edited many questions/answers
- Flagged many questionable questions/answers's to moderators
- Actively participate on community meta topics
- Eager to get the [beta](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/78/361) to proceed
- Enjoyed being a bit part of the Magento.SE community!

NB. This account belongs to Ben Lessani.

[Meta Profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/361/sonassi)
[Magento Profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/361/sonassi)
[Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1055401/sonassi?tab=accounts)

Answer (score 14):

#### Alan Storm

I would like to nominate Alan Storm. Here is his [main profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4/alan-storm) and [meta profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/alan-storm).

Answer (score 11):

#### Fabian Blechschmidt

I would like to nominate Fabian Blechschmidt. Here is his [main profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt) and [meta profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt).

EDIT: I proudly accept the nomination.

Comment: Thanks for nomination, I'm not sure, whether I can offer always time, but together we'll do it :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - you'll make for a fine mod. Be sure to edit the post above if you accept

Answer (score 7):

#### Alex

I would like to nominate Alex. Here is his [main profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/81/alex) and [meta profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/81/alex).

**EDIT: I proudly accept the nomination.**

Answer (score 7):

#### David Alger

I would like to nominate David Alger... yep, that's me. :)

- [Main Profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/128/davidalger)
- [Meta Profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/128/davidalger)

It's been really awesome to see the rock-star Magento community pick up and run with this SO site once it launched into public beta, to be a part of promoting and kickstarting it, as well as seeing the dedication of some of the individuals who helped participate in the A51 proposal to make it all come together.

Answer (score 6):

#### Marius

I would like to nominate Marius. Here is his [main profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) and [meta profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius).
**EDIT: I can give it a try.**

Answer (score 6):

#### philwinkle

I would like to nominate myself - here is my [main profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/336/philwinkle) and my [meta profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/philwinkle). Here is my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/284197/philwinkle?tab=top).

- I have been active in the Magento Community, especially the freenode IRC, since 2008
- I am on Magento.SE and StackOverflow all day, every day (42 consecutive at the time of this writing)
- ## 7 overall in reputation

At any rate, it's a privilege to share the same Q&A space as the people I revere so highly - Alan Storm, Ben Marks, Vinai Kopp, others.

Comment: +1 Upvote for a fellow SE'er. Solid questions and answers and a mature attitude to boot. *Although we can't help feeling left out of the awesome people list :D*

Comment: Thank you. You're a force to be reckoned with. I respect you *because I fear you*. :D

Answer (score 3):

I would like to help support the community as a moderator

- [My Meta Profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/250/jeffrey-l-roberts)
- [My Magento SE Profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/250/jeffrey-l-roberts)