# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Tim]
[image: benmarks]
[image: Alex]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. Many fine folks [stepped up to volunteer](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/moderators-needed), and my failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for driving this, Anna, there had to be some touch choices. I'm sure each of us not picked have some level of disappointment or another; but I'm certain the individuals who have been chosen to fill this role will do a **great** job! :)

Comment: Disappointment? Oh no. More free time :D Congratulations! :-)

Comment: @benmarks: Do you think it is time for a re-election?

Comment: @Alex We don't periodically replace pro-tem moderators. (Or elected moderators, for that matter.) We monitor activity levels and add more mods where needed. And, of course, anyone is welcome to step down if they'd rather not continue moderating.