# Moderator Nomination - Round 2

Tags: discussion, moderators

I assume that it is unusual for a Beta to have another round of Moderator Nomination, but we are not only some time old, we also have reached an impressive number of questions and users. And as the graduation can still need some time, I suggest we nominate additional moderators to reduce burden.

Last Moderators Nomination: [Moderators Needed](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/moderators-needed)

You can read there anything important about the process, and how you apply and so on.

also the general informations about moderators in Betas: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/

**[EDIT]** by Marius
When nominating yourself please add some stats about your activity on the website so far. You can get them from your dashboard.

- Join date
- Number of days on the website
- Helpful flags raised
- Number of moderation badges (different and total count) - Please..just [moderation badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732)
- Number of vote casts
- Number of posts edited

Don't mention your reputation. It is not relevant for a moderator to have a high reputation (and if we can already see it just below your name anyway).

Comment: Some extra moderators would be nice, I know the current ones are working hard to keep the forum clean but it's a lot of work

Comment: I know that Alex hasn't stepped down and he's not really doing much work with Magento - but do we need a 4th moderator? Or should we just ask Alex to give up his spot? Also - can we just *decide* to elect a new moderator? I'm pretty sure that we have to engage our SE community manager.

Comment: There are some with less, some more then three. http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators
There are even some with 8.

Comment: You should probably state in your question that this is not official as it does not come from the StackExchange team.... Some self nominations are just silly. And by the way...that's a good idea.

Comment: I hope it should be clear from the linked blog post, which points out, that this usually gets initialized by the communities them self and then just calls for global moderators to follow the result.

Comment: I doubt that everyone reads the links you posted. At least add to the question what a nomination should look like. It's not that easy to look through each nominated person's stats to see if they deserve to be a moderator. When we will graduate this will be done automatically. Until then we have no choice. I would go at least for "helpful flags raised", "vote cast" (maybe not important), "days on the website", "join date", "number of moderation badges". Feel free to add anything else you think it's useful.

Comment: I don't think that this nomination is official unless we're trying to actively ask one of our other moderators to step down. There's no cause for having 4 moderators with only 3 active. We need to ask Alex to step down if he's not fully active. My $0.02.

Comment: @philwinkle. Maybe you should start a meta thread for this. (take my 0.02$ so you'll break even).

Comment: @philwinkle i would like to see you as moderator

Comment: I appreciate it but there are people way more active currently! :)

Comment: What is the progress??

Comment: It's great to see all this nomination activity, and I'm sorry nobody from the team commented earlier. The reason that we were holding off is that I proposed Magento SE for graduation. I have good news and bad news. The good news is that you've passed, as you might have expected based on the [recent announcement about graduation criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614). The bad news is that we're not quite ready to give you a design or [other benefits of graduation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754) just yet (which is why this is only a comment and not a full post). (cont'd...)

Comment: (cont'd...) This is entirely our fault, not yours. But with all that being said, the one "separated graduation feature" we have successfully tested recently is moderator elections. So, instead of appointing you a new pro tem moderator, __I'm going to add Magento to the election queue__. We have several sites already in that queue at the moment, but your turn will come up in about a month. Keep watching meta for more information!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it might get confused with the real election. This is not the real moderator election, but it was a good exercise for what's to come.

Answer (score 20):

**David Manners**

- [Profile link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/158/david-manners)
- helpful flags: 524
- Member for 2 years, 4 months
- 782 days on the website
- Moderation badges: 21 different, 31 in total
- 3495 vote casts
- 207 posts edited

Answer (score 16):

**Anna Völkl**

I would like to nominate [Anna Völkl](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/231/anna-v%C3%B6lkl) ([meta Profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/231/anna-v%C3%B6lkl))

As one of the organizers of http://magestackday.com/ she did a lot to improve this Community.

- helpful flags: 38
- Member for 2 years, 4 months
- Moderation badges: 15 different, 20 in total
- 889 vote casts
- 63 posts edited

Comment: Thanks for nomination, I feel very honoured. I'm not sure if I can offer as much time as this community deserves and needs, but I'm willing to help.

Answer (score 13):

I would like to nominate [Fabian Blechschmidt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt)

- [Profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt)
- 959 answers,
- 9 questions,
- ~715k people reached,
- 138 helpful flags,
- 2,298 votes cast,
- Member for 2 years, 4 months
- 149 posts edited

Comment: Thanks, this would be an honor, but I think I'm unregular user, so if someone fills my gaps, this would work ;)

Answer (score 12):

**Sander Mangel**

- [Profile link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel)
- helpful flags: 89
- Member for 2 years, 4 months
- 690 days on the website
- Moderation badges: 14 different, 20 in total
- 574 vote casts
- 117 posts edited

Comment: Rotterdam!!! No serious, besides that, I also think Sander is really valuable to our Magento SE...

Comment: Thanks for nominating and the vote. Always glad to help out on the forum :)

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate Philwinkle

- [Profile](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/philwinkle)
- 114 posts edited
- 91 helpful flags
- 1,040 votes cast
- 537 answers
- ~916k people reached
- Member for 2 years, 4 months

Comment: only one nomination per post please, and make our life easier by following the formating rules pointed out in the Question.

Comment: Please add their stat's instead of profile links.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Amit Bera](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera)

- [Profile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera)
- 1,085 Answers
- 48 Questions
- 330k People reached
- Member for 1 year, 5 months
- 1,479 votes cast
- 65 helpful flags
- 628 posts edited

Comment: thanks for nominate for moderator. I am  very glad for this.thanks again

Comment: 15385 Rep 65 Helpful flags not a great combination.

Comment: 15385 Reputation ,,,330k People reached and many things are good combination for nomination @dh47,,check his profile for more information

Comment: i think you should check his profile @dh47

Comment: Thanks Keyur for support me again....  will try  improve my all the section of MSE. Will try to help  growth of  MSE

Comment: +1 for his infinite support in MSE and love towards Magento. Kudos to Amit

Comment: still i dont understand why dh47 said its not great combination @RajeevKTomy

Comment: @KeyurShah thanks for nominating him. Amit is one among most active user in this community. I studied a lot from him and I believe he is eligible. if you are reading this dh47, amit is 5th most scored member in MSE. Almost every month, he gains most points after the legendary Marius (he is unbeatable). He spends lot of time here in MSE. So dont under-estimate the power of Amit, an Indian Legend

Comment: But Amit should increase his moderating abilities. When compare with other members, he is lagging with moderation aspects. But still he fits for the position of a moderator.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy yeah i have also studied a lots of thing from him and his contribution is also useful fro many developers,,,,let see what happen

Comment: @RajeevKTomy sorry for late response. See Iam not having any personal grudge on amit or someone I admit he is contributing to MSE very much but being an active member and on high scoring reputation he should also concentrate on flag's I have seen him editing Thankyou or signature it is good though but along with that flag's are very important in any SE sites FLAG's play a key role in increasing Moderator abilities no offence sorry if my comments hurt anyone.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy  Please no at least don't bring on region's here No India no USA we belong to Magento.

Comment: RajeevKTomy, KeyurShah thanks for support. Dear @RajeevKTomy,kindly don't make me `Indian Legend`. I am small guys who try to  give his best for MSE..... I have note your point for  my improve  moderator  abilities.Greats thanks  both of you.

Comment: dh47  thanks for your point of view on my profile.I shall try to improve to  my activities on MSE.

Comment: #Keyur,#Rajeev and #dh4,  guys .... please to shake hands of  each other and keep smile for  MSE....

Comment: @dh47 what I mean by Indian Legend is, Amit is the MOST SCORED INDIAN. It is a unique tag and unbeatable. So I think he is an Indian Legend. If that hurts any one, let me call him as a Magento veteran.

and you said it is not a great combination. But with all respect, I deny. I believe his profile is great and we can nominate him obviously

Comment: @AmitBera me, Keyur, dh47 is not making dispute here. Rather we are expressing our thoughts. thumbs_up to dh47 & keyur

Comment: @RajeevKTomy :) :)

Comment: we are just expressing our personal thought so cool guys ,,,,@RajeevKTomy , @Amit ,,,@dh47,,,,,enjoy

Answer (score 0):

[***Miguel Balparda***](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/5209/mbalparda)

I volunteer as Tribute! I mean Moderator, sorry about that.

- Member for 1 year, 4 months
- 45 Helpful flags
- 18 Posts edited
- 132 Votes cast
- 6 Moderation badges

Comment: Please edit your answer with the stats as requested by Marius

Comment: Ok I did it for you.

Comment: I think you can contribute lot as a moderator and thus +1 from my part :-)

Answer (score -7):

I nominate myself to position of High Council Chairman, thank you.

Comment: with 6 flags raised, 119 votes cast and 5 moderation badges, I doubt you are the right person for the job or that you even stand a chance.

Comment: @Marius 5 badges thank you very much!

Comment: OK. my bad. I will edit the comment.