# It's election and graduation eve!

Tags: discussion, moderators

First things first:

### CONGRATULATIONS, MAGENTO STACK EXCHANGE IS GRADUATING!

A few weeks ago, I quietly dropped [a comment](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594/moderator-nomination-round-2#comment2826_594) on the 2015 moderator nomination post to say that we on the SE team wouldn't be appointing a new pro tem moderator... because you had been approved for graduation, and we wanted to give you a moderator election instead. The comment didn't seem to get much attention, which was just fine with me; I intentionally didn't make a big deal about it because we didn't have the details ironed out at the time.

But now we do! (Or, at least, we're a lot closer.) As I alluded to above, the fact that you've graduated means that your pro tem mods' terms of service are ending, and you now get to elect your own moderators from within your community. **Magento's first moderator election will begin on Monday, August 17, 2015.** Please join me in taking a moment to thank Alex, benmarks, Marius and your past pro tem mods for all their work getting the site to where it is today!

Before you get too excited about the upcoming election, there is a bit more news; this isn't just an election announcement. As those of you who follow network-wide events may know, we announced [some changes to the way we think about the site lifecycle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) earlier this year, and the response to that announcement made us start work on [breaking up the elements of graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) into independent pieces. On Monday, when your election starts, you'll be the first site that gets to try out this new "graduation without design" approach.

Specifically, this means:

- you will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- you will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- you will be able to select your own community ads

Since you are the first site to get these features outside of dev, there may be more bugs than normal. Please report any that you see here on meta like you would any other bug.

Comment: What fantastic news! The hard work has paid off!

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you everyone who has put in so much hard work.

Comment: WOOOOOOOOHOOOOOO :D

Comment: yes.. We reach destiny. Congrts too all..:)

Comment: Wohooo this is the moment we (MSE people) waiting a long for it is looking like a festival with graduation and moderator elections, way to go congrats to everyone and All the Best for nominators

Answer (score 30):

This has been a long time coming. Thanks for making such an amazing place for us to hang out.

Magento brand team is eager to get involved. In the past I believe that eBay Enterprise's creative team has said they'd help.

Hip-hip-hooray!

Comment: Do you still own this www.mageoverflow.com domain we've secured for graduation?

Comment: We get an own domain? Looks like @philwinkle owns mageoverflow.com

Comment: @fschmengler correct and I'm happy to hand over at any time.

Comment: [It's unlikely that we'll get our own domain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248455/188727), though I'd love it if we did get to use MageOverflow.com.

Answer (score 13):

This is a great news... Thanks everyone who made this really possible..

We together worked for this a lot. Finally it paid off..

First of all, Thanks to Marius, the great teacher. His work in this site is unimaginable. As a member and moderator of this site, he is always close to us and is directing us in the right way.

Second Kudos goes to #MageStackDay. Thanks Sander and Anna for organizing those amazing days. It brought us from 68% to 82% answer ratio. I can say this event is definitely a historic event for us, the magento community.

Thanks Benmarks and Alex. You are awesome, we are sure.

I want to mention Alanstorm, Fabian, Amit for their amazing contributions to this community..

Finally, congratulations every one... thanks for bring us from beta.. Now inhale and exhale Magento. This is our independence day !!!!

Comment: Thank *you* for your contribution!

Comment: @philwinkle thanks for u and ur broadcast !!

Comment: gald to hear that ,,thanks all for contribution